# How do I add a procedural confetti pattern to a plaster wall?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

Okay,I'm gonna ask this again and I'm gonna be more specific. Do you remember in FNaF how you see a triangle shaped confetti texture on the walls? The clearest view of it is in the West Hall as displayed in the image below. Well,I am trying to find out if this can be done procedurally or if I have to use an image texture for it.

[image]

Can someone please help me out? If you can,I'll give you a big,fat thumbs up and I'll check your question as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168499/35559) gives a basic polygon-distance-function, which can be used to make a polygon-shader. Here, it's slightly adapted to give inputs for sides and size:

[image]

.. and incorporated in a group which:

- Gives a UV-per-cell of a Voronoi buy subtracting 'Position' from the texture coordinate
- Scales the polygons in that UV by the N-sphere radius of a parallel Voronoi, to prevent clipping by the cells.

[image]

it outputs the polygon-mask and color sparately.

It can be used on its own for a non-overlapping scatter, or masked against another version of itself for overlaps:

[image]

With results like this:

[image]

( The polygons could have as many sides as you like)

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Also, sorry for the dumb question. I asked it when I was still in high school and not as experienced as I am now. Still need more, but at least it's better. Thank you.

Comment: @JeremiahTDK hehe .. I'm touched!  It wasn't a dumb question at all! (I suppose the reference could have been a little clearer, that's all   :)   )

Answer (score 5):

You will need to do this with a texture. (I have created a seamless texture for you) I don't believe there are triangle shapes with nodes, so I dont think this can be done procedural.

Here is the [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwapshzcvwse7z9/Triangle%204K%20Seamless.jpg?dl=0) for a seamless 4K texture I made real quick in PS.

This one below is just a reference of what it looks like.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you icYou,this is just what I needed,and thank you for providing this texture for me.

Now I can use this in my fan game Five Nights at Tanya's.

Comment: Hey! The link is no longer supported. Could you please send a new one?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I was making my own scene in Blender when I cam across this question and thought I'd give my own interpretation. Pretty much the same as Duarte, but with some real specific placement on the Color Ramp in 2022. idk.

Comment: You could have procedural  triangles if you wanted.. I've posted another answer

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can get with procedural textures alone is *Cycles Voronoi* texture set to *Cells*.

Run it through a *Color Ramp* node to control the output color,

[image]