# Node editor Hexagon

Tags: node-editor, add-on, shaders, mathematics, procedural

I currently have the Maths expressions addon installed in blender.
I know it has a hexagon preset already, but it comes up with this:
[image]

1) How do I fix this?

2) How do I make a hexagon?

Comment: It looks as though, somewhere, your/the generated  expression is trying to access the 4th element of a list of size 3. In the mean time, there's a hand-rolled version [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161799/35559)

Answer (score 7):

This tree will produce distance-function along the 'spokes' perpendicular to the edges of an Ngon centered on the 0 of a given UV space.

It works by splitting the radial angle into (`sides`) angular regions, each region with shading-point values from (`-pi/sides`) to (`pi/sides`), and multiplying the cosine of those values with the distance from the texture space origin. If the result is put through a threshold (the color ramp), it produces a polygon with `sides` sides.

[image]

For the sake of illustration, I've plugged the Pass Index of the plane objects into the `sides` input. That's where you would enter `6` for a hexagon.

[image]